# pushnotification for Advertisement in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I have developed an iOS app which uses a third party framework for showing Ads inside the app.

I would like to know whether to enable push notifications for the AppId While submiting App?[image]

Comment: It is not clear from your question that your application is having push notifications configured or not?

Comment: I didn't configured any push notification inside my app .But I am using a third part framework for showing ads inside my app.So for showing such ads also do I want to configure push notification?

Comment: If the 3rd party is an advertisement SDK then no.

Comment: @coder1010: I did submit the app to App Store.But I am getting a message from apple review team.I will add its screenshot in question...

Comment: Yes it is an advertisment SDK.

Comment: What Advertisement SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

its depends on how the Ads SDK works.
most likely it works without the APNS (apple push notification server), but its also possible that it does, and from that screenshot, there is a good chance.

I would recommend enabling push notification, just in case.

go to the **[apple's developer member center](http://developer.apple.com/membercenter)**, go to your App, press edit, enable **"push notifications"** and create certificate for production, and also new provisioning profiles.

Don't forget to download the APNS certificate, create a PEM file to implement it on the server side (most likely they'll require that in case they do use APNS)

for more information on how it's done:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Enabling push notification is not required for Ad integration while submitting app to the App Store.